# How to change partial color change on header

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to get the left part of overflow header in white color and right side of the header to be in the header color. I am trying to fix the header size when we view in ultrawide screen.[Part of the header before logo image should be white and right should be of the same color as the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu3Wr.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more, which is left part of overflow header, what is overflow header and what is header color and what do u mean by ultrawide screen in terms of dimensions?

Comment: Hey @mding5692 thats for your response and I am trying to work with the 1280px screen and there is a logo in the header which is of white color as seen in the attached image and I am trying to get the left side of the logo in the white color and right side with blue color. the screen has to be responsive. I have used media queries for that.